# My OCR1A is changing even when 'if' condition is not met

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm trying to code a simple PWM servo control that uses pin 11 on the Arduino Mega 2560. This servo should turn CW (clockwise) or CCW (counterclockwise) depending on pressing and holding one of the two buttons (L and R). The problem I seem to be running into is that the variable I have set to change the OCR1A(i) is incrementing even when the 'if' statements are not true. The buttons work as I've tested using the `Serial.println(PINA)` to make sure. I'm really not sure where I've gone wrong. I would appreciate any help.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  TCCR1A |= (1<<COM1A1)|(1<<WGM11)|(1<<WGM10);
  TCCR1B = 0B00001100; // set mode 7 and prescale to 256
  DDRB |= (1<<PB5); // data direction register for PORTB(pwm output pin 11)
  DDRA = (1<<2)|(1<<3); // Last 2 digits of PORTA are inputs
  Serial.begin(9600); //initialize the serial
}

void loop() {
  int   i = 63;
  // This value controls the duty cycle, duty(%) = OCR1A/255*100
  // 63 is just a random start position
  OCR1A = i;
  int swL;
  int swR;
  swL = PINA & 0b00000001;
  swR = PINA & 0b00000010;
  while(i<160) {
    if (swR != 0b00000001) {
      i++; // increments OCR1A when button R is pressed
      Serial.println(PINA); // For testing button is pressed
      Serial.println(OCR1A); // debugging use
      Serial.println(i); // debugging use
      delay(100);
    }
    if(swL != 0b00000010) {
      i--; // negative increments when button L is pressed
      Serial.println(PINA);
      Serial.println(OCR1A);
      Serial.println(i);
      delay(100);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're masking `swR` with 0b10 and then comparing with 0b01. So the `if` is always true.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `PINA & 0b00000001` provides some value to `swL`. Now I am not able to find the initial value of `PINA` but I assume that it is another variable having binary value and so when the two values perform a ***Bit-wise AND*** they provide a **different value** to `swL`.

I suppose this is the reason why the if condition 
`if (swL != 0b00000001)` evaluates to `TRUE` and it then enters the if statement.

The same happens to the other variable `swR` and so it also enters the `if statement`.

I may be wrong but have a look at the lines:

`swL = PINA & 0b00000001;
 swR = PINA & 0b00000010;`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it turns out I just needed an extra set of eyes. My swR and swL were swapped. with a few other changes it now works as intended. Thank you all.